# Add image to first child in expandablelistview and hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap, imageview, expandablelistview

I am relatively new to java programming and running into a problem. In my project, Im using an expandable list adapter to create an expandable listview with header and child which needs to be populated from different activities.

My intention is to add a figure to only the first child, and textviews to the others. How to do this? And how to populate this imageview from the different activities (so the image needs to be different accross different activities).
Thanks in advance!

**Expandablelistadapter**:

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private final List<String> listDataHeader;
private final HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return listDataHeader.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1); //i = group item, i1 = childItem.
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(i);
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }
    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    if (i == 0)
        lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ca4e18"));

    if (i == 0)
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));

    else
        lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(i, i1);
    if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
    }


    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);


    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
```

}

**One of the activities:**

public class activity extends Activity {

```
private ExpandableListView listView;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    
    // super oncreate/
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity);

    listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    initData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,listDataHeader,listHash);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ace.this, DrugDosagesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


private void initData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listHash = new HashMap<>();

    listDataHeader.add("text");
    listDataHeader.add("2nd text");
    listDataHeader.add("3rd text");
    listDataHeader.add("4th text");
    listDataHeader.add("....");


    List<String> zero = new ArrayList<>();
    zero.add("text, but this needs to be a figure" );

    List<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    first.add("first text");

    List<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
    second.add("second text");

    List<String> third = new ArrayList<>();
    third.add("third text");

    List<String> fourth = new ArrayList<>();
    fourth.add("fourth text.");

    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0), zero);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1), first);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(2), second);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(3), third);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(4), fourth);


}
```

}

Comment: you can create a layout for the child with imageView and with textView. And in your  if statement: if(i==0), set the visibility of the text to GONE an the visibility of the image to VISIBLE. and do the opposite in the Else statement

Comment: Thanks Roish! But wouldn't that leave a gap for one of both views?

Comment: It does, if you set the visibility to INVISIBLE, but GONE "remove" the view from the layout. If you have one view aligned to the bottom of another one, and you set the top one to GONE. the second will "jump" up.